# I get 'error: incompatible types' when I try to return an array from within a method

Tags: java, incompatibletypeerror

I cannot seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to return the array D but the exact error message i get is:

```
Pa4.java:74: incompatible types
found   : double[]
required: double
return D;
       ^
```

The method I'm having trouble with is as follows.

```
static double diff(double[] C){

  double D[];
  D = new double[(C.length-1)];
  for(int i = C.length; i > 0; i -= 1){
    int deg = 1;
    D[i] = deg * C[i];
    deg++;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < C.length; i++){
    D[i] = C[i];
  }
  return D;
}
```

The full code I have is as follows. It's very incomplete, so hopefully the problem is in the first block of code i gave:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
class Pa4{



  public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int degree;
    double C[];

    double resolution = 10^(-2);
    double threshhold = 10^(-3);
    double tolerance = 10^(-7);



    System.out.print("Enter the degree: ");
    degree = sc.nextInt();

    C = new double[degree];
    System.out.print("Enter "+(degree+1)+" coefficients: ");

    for(int i = 0; i < degree+1; i++){             // 1st number = last to enter
      C[i] = sc.nextInt();                         //stores coefficiant values in reverse order in an array
    }

    System.out.print("Enter the left and right endpoints: ");
    int a = sc.nextInt();                       
    int b = sc.nextInt();

    double x = findRoot(C, a, b, tolerance);
    double saf = poly(C, x);
    double sdf = diff(C);
    double asdf = poly(D, x);


  }


  static double poly(double[] C, double x){

    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= C.length; i =- i){
      int deg = 1;
      deg++;
      double hold = Math.pow(C[i], deg);
      hold = hold*x;
      sum = hold+sum;
    }
    return sum;
  }

  static double diff(double[] C){

    double D[];
    D = new double[(C.length-1)];
    for(int i = C.length; i > 0; i -= 1){
      int deg = 1;
      D[i] = deg * C[i];
      deg++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < C.length; i++){
      D[i] = C[i];
    }
    return D;
  }

  static double findRoot(double[] C, double a, double b, double tolerance){
    double x = 0; 
    double width = b-a;
    while(width > tolerance){
      x = (a + b)/2.0;
      if((a*a-2.0)*(x*x-2.0) < 0){
        b = x;
      }else{
        a = x;
      }
      width = b-a;
    }  
    return x;
               //use precondition (?)
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to return a `double[]`, then why is the return type `double`?

Answer (score 2):

Your `diff` method returns a single `double`, but you try to return a `double` array. Change the return type to `double[]`, and change the call to `double[] sdf = diff(C);`

BTW, your diff method has other problems :

1. The D array has a length of C.length - 1, but you try to assign the entire C array to D. You'll get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
2. Most of the code of that method makes no sense, since the second loop assigns the elements of C to D, so the entire body of the method can be replaced with `return C`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm aware of the first error, but it wasn't my main focus. 

Yes, diff doesn't make much sense. i accidentally forgot to delete that bit of code. 

Again, thank you so much for taking the time to respond!